# How do I display only the events of a class in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Visual studio 15 differentiates the fields of the class by category and icon too:

[image]

For example, in the above screenshot, `SizeChanged` is an *event*, `Style` is a *property* and `Start` is a *method*.

What can I do to only see events? (Items with a lightning icon, such as `SizeChanged`, etc)

Comment: VS2017 supports filtering of entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Visual Studio** doesn't have this kind of feature *(explicit type filtering)* for `IntelliSense`, but there is a Visual add-in called [Visual Asset X](http://www.wholetomato.com/features/feature-coding-assistance.asp) which enables filtering by events (as well as properties, methods, etc.) and there is also one made by JetBrains called [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.3/Using_Filters_in_Code_Completion.html).

Hope it helps!